# Android call state through the "call" class (API 23)

Tags: android, state, phone-call, telephony

Please help,
 I need to find out the detailed status of the calls. I found the "call" class ("https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html") that should give these states. Unfortunately, I have found no way to use this class and get the statuses.

Comment: As in you want to code some functionality reaction based on a phone's state such as when it's ringing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) instead which was added in API 1.

A sample scenario of implementing this class is as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // TODO: Code your functionality response here

                    break;

                // TODO: Configure other phone state cases here if you want
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
                getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

And remember to include the phone state permission into your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found the previous solution. I am looking for solutions with more detailed states such as these, and the "call" class provides: STATE_ACTIVE, STATE_CONNECTING, STATE_DIALING, STATE_DISCONNECTED, STATE_DISCONNECTING, STATE_HOLDING, STATE_NE, STATE_PULLING_CALL, STATE_RINGING. I have been looking everywhere on the Internet unfortunately, I have not found a example of using a "call" class. Here I found several similar queries that were not answered.

Comment: Thanks for the previous answer, but it does not solve my problem. I want to ask, is it possible to check the status of the called phone number if it exists or not?